# SFTP BSD Zsh Batchfile with Expect Syntax

Tags: sftp, zsh, expect, bsd

I have a zsh script in MacOS—trying to automate the -b (batchfile option) but the "~" doesn't seem to be expanding within the expect syntax. Expect can't find the batchfile location in that directory even though it's there. Do I need the full path or do globals like $HOME not work within expect?

```
deletedfiles=$(/usr/bin/expect <<SFTP
    set timeout -1
    spawn /usr/bin/sftp -b ~/Desktop/pgmfilesremoved.txt Port=${port} ${sftpuser}@${host}
    expect "Password authentication"
    expect "Password:"
    send "${password}\r"
    expect "sftp>"
    send "exit\r"
    SFTP
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the heredoc is unquoted, the shell is expanding the variables before launching expect. Use `$HOME`: tilde has no special significance in Tcl/expect.